# On nilpotent groups of class 2

Tags: solution-verification, nilpotent-groups

So I have a simple question: I would like to know if the converse of this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2919637/if-g-is-a-nilpotent-group-of-class-2-show-g-%e2%89%a4-zg) is also true, that is, if $G$ is a group with $G'\leq Z(G)$ then $G$ is a nilpotent group of class 2.

I'm inclined to think this is true. By the definition of a nilpotent group we need to find a central series for $G$ with length 2. I claim that this series must be the following series:
$$
1  \leq G' \leq G.
$$

All I have to do now is check if the quotients are central. In fact, by assumption we have
$$
G'/1 = G' \subseteq Z(G) = Z(G/1)
$$

For the inclusion $G/G' \subseteq Z(G/G')$, we use the fact that $G/G'$ is abelian.

I just want to know if my argument is correct.

Comment: A group is nilpotent of class *at most* 2 if and only if $[G,G]\subseteq Z(G)$. The only minor issue in your argument is that you don't know for sure the series has length 2, because the commutator subgroup could be trivial.

Comment: Oh I see that. So if I add the hypothesis that the commutator subgroup is nontrivial, then my argument would become correct?